# Animated Geographical Maps in R with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I can generate some decent-looking choropleth maps in R, see for instance the following

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth) 
library(rnaturalearthdata)

set.seed(1234)

ww <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

ll <- ww$name %>% length

val <- sample(c("a","b","c","d"), ll, replace=T)
bb <- ne_download(type = "wgs84_bounding_box", category = "physical",
              returnclass = "sf")

ww <- ww %>% mutate(value=val)


gpl1 <- ggplot(data = ww) +
geom_sf(aes(fill=value),  col = "black", lwd = 0.3 )+
xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) +
ggtitle("World Export of Merchandise")+
geom_sf(data = bb, col = "grey", fill = "transparent") +
theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"),
      legend.position="top",
      plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, size=24, face="bold",
                                vjust=1),
      legend.text = element_text(vjust=.4,lineheight=1,size = 14),
      legend.title = element_text(vjust=1,lineheight=1, size=14,
                                  face="bold" ))+
coord_sf(crs = "+proj=eqearth +wktext") 

ggsave("test_world1.pdf", gpl1, width=6*1.618,height=5)
```

but then suppose that I have data for several years, for instance

```
values_years <- tibble(value=sample(c("a","b","c","d"), 4*ll, replace=T),
            years=sample(seq(4), 4*ll, replace=T))
```

does anyone know how to use gganimate to generate a choropleth map where the country colors change automatically while showcasing different years?
I am not looking for an interactive viz, but something like this

https://www.blog.cultureofinsight.com/2017/09/animated-choropleth-maps-in-r/

just I am having a hard time to simplify that example to my needs.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert at either geospatial data or gganimate, but I managed to get something that resembles an answer to your question by doing the following. We'll start out in a similar fashion to how you started your example, but we also load the gganimate package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth) 
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(gganimate) # also needs transformr

## Do all previous stuff
set.seed(1234)

ww <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

ll <- ww$name %>% length

val <- sample(c("a","b","c","d"), ll, replace=T)
bb <- ne_download(type = "wgs84_bounding_box", category = "physical",
                  returnclass = "sf")
ww <- ww %>% mutate(value=val)
```

Then, for each of our timepoints, we copy the data and assign a group per shape, timepoint and new fill variable. The grouping is need because by default, the fill will determine the grouping and the animations will show countries all jumping across the map.

```
newdf <- lapply(seq_len(5), function(i) {
  new <- ww
  new$group <- seq_len(nrow(new))
  new$value <- sample(letters[1:4], nrow(new), replace = TRUE)
  new$time <- i
  new
})
newdf <- do.call(rbind, newdf)
```

Then we make a plot. The main difference is that I assign a group in the `geom_sf()` and add `transition_time(time)`. Also, I add a subtitle to keep track of the animation state.

```
gpl1 <- ggplot(data = newdf) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=value, group = group),  col = "black", lwd = 0.3 )+
  xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) +
  ggtitle("World Export of Merchandise", subtitle = "{frame_time}")+
  geom_sf(data = bb, col = "grey", fill = "transparent") +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"),
        legend.position="top",
        plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, size=24, face="bold",
                                  vjust=1),
        legend.text = element_text(vjust=.4,lineheight=1,size = 14),
        legend.title = element_text(vjust=1,lineheight=1, size=14,
                                    face="bold" )) +
  transition_time(time)
  # coord_sf(crs = "+proj=eqearth +wktext") # couldn't get this coord to work
```

And then we animate:

```
ani <- animate(gpl1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, but I think I found something simpler.

```
library(tidyverse)

library(rnaturalearth) 
library(rnaturalearthdata)

library(gganimate)

set.seed(1234)

ww_ini <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

ll <- ww_ini$name %>% length

val <- sample(c("a","b","c","d"), ll, replace=T)



bb <- ne_download(type = "wgs84_bounding_box", category = "physical",
              returnclass = "sf")

ww <- ww_ini %>%
mutate(value=val)


gpl1 <- ggplot(data = ww) +
geom_sf(aes(fill=value),  col = "black", lwd = 0.3 )+
xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) +
ggtitle("World Export of Merchandise")+
 geom_sf(data = bb, col = "grey", fill = "transparent") +
theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"),
      legend.position="top",
      plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, size=24, face="bold",
                                vjust=1),
      legend.text = element_text(vjust=.4,lineheight=1,size = 14),
      legend.title = element_text(vjust=1,lineheight=1, size=14,
                                  face="bold" ))+
coord_sf(crs = "+proj=eqearth +wktext") 

ggsave("test_world1.pdf", gpl1, width=6*1.618,height=5)



values_years <- tibble(name=rep(ww$name,4),
                   year=c(rep(1,ll), rep(2,ll), rep(3, ll), rep(4, ll)),
                   value=sample(c("a","b","c","d"),4* ll, replace=T))


 ww_ext <- left_join(ww_ini, values_years, by="name")



gpl2 <- ggplot(data = ww_ext) +
geom_sf(aes(fill=value),  col = "black", lwd = 0.3 )+
xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) +
ggtitle("World Export of Merchandise")+
 geom_sf(data = bb, col = "grey", fill = "transparent") +
theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey"),
      legend.position="top",
      plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, size=24, face="bold",
                                vjust=1),
      legend.text = element_text(vjust=.4,lineheight=1,size = 14),
      legend.title = element_text(vjust=1,lineheight=1, size=14,
                                  face="bold" ))+
 coord_sf(crs = "+proj=eqearth +wktext") +

transition_manual(year )

anim <- animate(gpl2)
```

It still is a bit trial and error, in particular when it comes to choosing the transition_ verb.